# std::invoke of a function template/lambda fails

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda

How can I get this working? (C++17/20)
Note: I have to use `std::invoke` here because in the real code, the only guarantee I have is that this callable is invokable.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> // to include everything

int main() {
    const auto func = [&]<typename T>(const std::string& h) {
        T t;
        std::cout << t << " " << h << "\n";
    };
    std::invoke(func<std::string>, std::string("Hello"));
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:17:33: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   17 |     std::invoke(func<std::string>, std::string("Hello"));
```

Comment: please do not remove includes from your code. They are needed to reproduce you error. WIthout the includes this code produces totally diffferent errors. Its effort you ask from others trying to compile the code that isnt necessary

Comment: I've included everything - using the header as such (this is just a dummy example that failed in godbolt, but it's enough to replicate the issue I'm facing in prod)

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a **private** compiler header file.  Don't include it yourself.

Comment: Like I mentioned it's just a dummy code to replicate the prod issue.

Comment: `func` is not a template. It has a templated `operator()`

Comment: How would you write that using std::invoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your lambda `func` is **not a function template**, but rather **has a templated `operator()`**.

One way to use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) the way you attempted, would be to actually change `func` into a **function template**:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
void func(const std::string& h)
{
    T t;
    std::cout << t << " " << h << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    std::invoke(func<std::string>, std::string("Hello"));
}
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9xzMohTna)

**A side note:** better to avoid [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 2):

lambda is not template, but its `operator()` is.

As `T` is not deducible, you might write:

```
std::invoke([&](const std::string &s) { func.operator()<std::string>(s); },
            std::string("Hello"));
```

or more "simply":

```
func.operator()<std::string>("Hello");
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ps1n5esa)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass the pointer-to-member function (`&decltype(f)::operator()<int>`), then give it the object (`f`) and the arguments(`std::string`)

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

int main() {
    const auto f = []<typename T>(std::string) -> void {};
    std::invoke(&decltype(f)::operator()<int>, f, "hello");
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).